# Is there a way to access the first element in a column on a website using VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

Here is a screenshot of a column in a website page.

[image]

It is located in that way in the website page :

[image]

As you can see, all the rows have a 'Completed' button you can pres and followed by a number of lines. These rows refer to exports. So the columnis not static and is constantly changing.

However, everytime i run the macro i want to access the first row of the column.

Here is a sample code of he HTML code of the first 'Completed' button in the screenshot above: 
[image]

I have many  that have the same class name. Look at the highlighted rows as an example in the picture below: 
[image]

I really have no idea how to write a VBA code to always access the first 'Completed' bytton in this column.

PS: In the HTML code, in the tag "a", the onclick="....." is constantly changing. So i cannot use this as an argument to access the desired field and click on the desired button.

Please if anyone could help me figure out how to do this, i would really be happy.

Thank you :)

Comment: Please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html so people can use it for testing. Include your current coding attempt as well. Also, review your html - is there a way for us to identify the table? Please remember to include url if possible.

Answer (score 0):

`<tr>` tags are rows, `<td>` tags are cells inside those rows. You did not provide enough code to show the entire table, but generally speaking to access the first row of a table, you would need to refer to the collection object and use the index number you want.

```
.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0)
```

This will refer to the first row of a table. Same with getting the first column *in the first row* of your table:

```
.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(0)
```

Once you tracked down the particular cell, now you are wanting to click the link. You can use the same method as above.

```
.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
```

And a final note, the first row of a table could be a header, so you may actually want the 2nd row `(1)` instead.

---

Thanks for updating with more HTML code. I am going to slightly switch gears and use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to grab the main table.

```
doc.querySelector("#divPage > table.advancedSearch_table > tbody"). _
            getElementsByTagName("tr")(3).getElementsByTagName("td")(3).Children(0).Click
```

See if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried entering your code as:
 ie3.getElementsByClassName("main_table_data advancedSearch_results_table grey_background").getElementsByTagName("td")(1).getElementsByTagName("a")(1).Click

Nothing is happening when i run the code .. Do you know how to fix this?
I added one more image about the HTML code of the page

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't it be `ie3.Document.getElements...`?

Comment: @K.Davis no because ie3 is set as 
Set ie3 = objShell3.Windows(x).document

Comment: It is still not working... @K.Davis

Nothing is happening when i run the new code you provided  using querySelector

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click the 'Completed' button in the first column, you can use the code below:

```
Set doc = objIE.Document
doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
```

The code get the first `<tr>` then get the first `<td>` then get `<a>` in it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried entering your code as:
 ie3.getElementsByClassName("main_table_data advancedSearch_results_table grey_background").getElementsByTagName("td")(1).getElementsByTagName("a")(1).Click

Nothing is happening when i run the code .. Do you know how to fix this?
I added one more image about the HTML code of the page

Thank you!

Comment: I think the edited answer of K.Dᴀᴠɪs is right. But there's a little mistake in the code, the number after `("td")` is wrong. You can use this: `doc.querySelector("#divPage > table.advancedSearch_table > tbody"). _
            getElementsByTagName("tr")(3).getElementsByTagName("td")(5).Children(0).Click`. I tried it on my side and it works.

Comment: It is still not working on my side... Please check the update above (i added a picture of the overall design of the website page) 
Thank you!

Comment: I think a link will be more useful. You can provide a link of the webpage and it will be more convenient for us to make a test.